# Referencing a user defined function in another

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

I have defined a time-dependent current as

```
it1[t_] := ((i01*(Exp[-α*t] - Exp[-β*t])))*HeavisideTheta[t]
```

This works fine; it plots correctly and is easy to manipulate. However, I need to embed this expression for the current into another expression that gives me the electric field. Right now, I've written that as

```
e[t_] := 
  1/(4*π*ϵ) * 
    (Integrate[
       (2*ell*i[t]/(d^3)) + (2*ell*i[t]/(c*(d^2))) + (D[i, t]/(d*(c^2))), 
       t])
```

While I don't get an error when I define it this way, I can't get any results out of it. For example, when I try to plot it like this:

```
Plot[e[t], {t, 0, 10^-5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I get a pile of errors. I've tried specifying limits to the integral, and I've tried numerical integration (`NIntegrate`) instead of symbolic integration (`Integrate`) in the definition of the field, but nothing works.

Does anyone see my error?

After this the next challenge is finding the Fourier transform the electric field.

Comment: Do the parameters `i01, alpha, beta, epsilon, d, ell, c` have specific numerical values? Or are they abstract parameters? The function `i` in the function `e` is the function `it1` from above?

Comment: You have defined `it1` and then use `i` in `e`?

Comment: The parameters i01, alpha, beta, epsilon, d, ell, and c all have specific values. The function i in the function e is the function it1 from above -- correct.

Answer (score 3):

```
it1[t_] := ((i01*(Exp[-\[Alpha]*t] - Exp[-\[Beta]*t])))*
  HeavisideTheta[t]
ell = 1; \[Epsilon] = 8.85418781*10^-6 ; d = 10; c = 
 10^8; \[Beta] = 3; \[Alpha] = 5; i01 = 10^-3;
e[t_] := 1/(4*\[Pi]*\[Epsilon])*(Integrate[(2*ell*it1[t]/(d^3)) + (2*
       ell*it1[t]/(c*(d^2))) + (D[it1[t], t]/(d*(c^2))), t])
Plot[e[t] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10^-5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

is ready for a plot:

[image: Plot of the electric field time behavior]

Mind set all values for proper constants for an evaluation for a plot.

Comment: When I add the Evaluate command, things behave as they should. Why do I need it?

Comment: Plot has the attribute `HoldAll` and `e[t_]` was defined with `SetDelayed`. You need to **either** use `Evaluate` in the `Plot` **or** change the definition of `e[t_]` to use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`.